# PHP mail() function send to Webmail doesn't work

Tags: php, email

I have tried mail() function in PHP for webmail, in example i want to send email with the address is xxxxx@moe.ac.id. But does'nt work, does anyone has a solution for this case? And the webmail service using gmail

Comment: Way too broad without code. Is SMTP enabled on server?

Comment: You say you use gmail, but you don't say much else. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error message (hint: look in your web servers error log, /var/log/apache2/error.log if you use Apache). Did you set the correct gmail credentials? You will need to use application credentials for gmail, rather than your regular username/password, due to 2-factor authentication. You need to post more details.